# c# autofac resolve issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am new to Autofac and not sure how can i pass object in the builder.

```
public class OrderFactory : IOrderFactory {
    private readonly IAffiliate _affiliate;
    private readonly IGetNewOrdersToImport _ordersToImportHelper;
    private readonly IOrderProcessor _orderProcessor;

    public OrderFactory(IAffiliate affiliate, IGetNewOrdersToImport ordersToImport, IOrderProcessor orderProcessor) {
        _affiliate =  affiliate;
        _ordersToImportHelper = ordersToImport;
        _orderProcessor = orderProcessor;
    }
}
```

**Bootstrap**

```
    public IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Channel>().As<IAffiliate>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrderFactory>().As<IOrderFactory>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

When the app runs, i am loading affiliate first and want to pass the affiliate in OrderFactory

**Program**

```
var channel = new Channel().Get(param);
var merchantOrderManager = _myContainer.Resolve<IOrderFactory>();
merchantOrderManager.ImportMerchantOrders();
```

so channel object is now populated with many properties and i want to access the Channel object in OrderFactory but i am getting affiliate null..

please advice

Comment: Which object exactly is `null`?

Comment: channel object is null when i try to access it in OrderFactory

Comment: Do you want to pass this specific channel defined in your snippet as a parameter to your factory?

Comment: @Moutabreath : yes... i want to pass that channel to all snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i created Repository and getting the channel from there...

```
public IContainer Configure(IAffiliate affiliate)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new ChannelRepository().Get(affiliate.Code)).As<IAffiliate>();
        builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<OrderFactory>().As<IOrderFactory>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

so this means that whenever OrderFactory is returned, i get the channel from ChannelRepository...